# Unknown React Component Comminucation

Tags: reactjs

I have 3 different components in my react program. All the three programs are used on the same page. Now I want whatever I write in my first and second textbox the input value will reflect in the third textbox. I don't know how to get reference or communicate between multiple components in reactjs.

Below is the code of all the files.

```
**First.js**
//import ReactDom from 'react-dom';   

var NameStateComponent = React.createClass({
    nameChanged: function(event) {
        this.setState({
            name: event.target.value
        });
        console.log(React.findDOMNode('finalRoot'));
    },

    getInitialState: function (){                                               
        return{
            name: ''
        }
    },
    render: function(){
        return( <div> <input type='text' onChange={this.nameChanged} />&nbsp;{this.state.name.length}</div> ) }});
ReactDOM.render(
<NameStateComponent />,
document.getElementById("firstRoot")
);

**Second.js**
var NameStateComponent = React.createClass({
    name2Changed: function(event){
        this.setState({
            name2 : event.target.value
        })
    }, 
    getInitialState: function (){                                               
        return{
            name2: ''
        }
    },
    render: function(){
        return( <div> <input type='text' onChange={this.name2Changed} />&nbsp;{this.state.name2.length}</div> ) }});
ReactDOM.render(
<NameStateComponent />,
document.getElementById("secondRoot")
);

**Third.js**
var FinalComponent = React.createClass({
    nameChanged: function(event){
        this.setState({

        })
    }, 
    getInitialState: function (){                                               
        return{
            name3: ''
        }
    },

    render: function(){
        return( <div> <input type='text'/></div> ) }});
ReactDOM.render(
<FinalComponent />,
document.getElementById("finalRoot")
);

**Index.html**
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>React Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        A<div id='firstRoot'></div> <br/>
        B<div id='secondRoot'></div><br/>
        C<div id='finalRoot'></div>
    </div>
    <script src="../react-15.0.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../react-dom-15.0.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../browser.min.js"></script>
    <script src="First.js" type="text/babel"></script>
    <script src="Second.js" type="text/babel"></script>
    <script src="Third.js" type="text/babel"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a look at Redux or MobX.

Answer (score 1):

With ReactJS communication between components happens *from up to down*. 
Basically a top parent component handle the state and pass it down to its child with props.

In your case, you would have a parent component storing the state of your 2 text fields and handling the change.

```
var Component = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
       return {
            val1: '',
            val2: ''
       }
  }, 
  handleChange: function(id, event) {
        var copyState = this.state;
        copyState[id] = event.target.value;
        this.setState(copyState);
   },

  render: function() {
    var concat = this.state.val1 + ' ' + this.state.val2;
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" value={this.state.val1} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'val1')} /> 
            <input type="text" value={this.state.val2} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'val2')}/> 
            <input type="text" value={concat} /> 
        </div>
    );
  }
});
```

See it in action [here](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/82118/)

Please note, you have to decide which behavior you want when we edit directly the third text field. I didn't bind an event handler on it on the jsfiddle.